# iOS: Application crashes after getting restarted after memory issue termination

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, debugging

I have an application written in Swift 2.1, under XCode 7.3. The steps to reproduce the issue are as follows:

1. Run application and then move it to background (etc. open another app etc.).
2. Play with other apps until our app gets "Terminated due to memory issue".
3. Try relaunching application through recently used apps menu (the one that shows after double clicking the Home button).

And now weird things happen. If the application is connected to XCode, the restart is flawless: app gets cold start and is running fine. However, when it is running standalone it crashes after few seconds of displaying last frozen screen. I am totally stuck: there is neither any sign of this crash in device logs, nor Crashlytics which we use to report crashes sends anything. There is also no problem with optimization, as some folks have suggested in other similar situations, since it happens on the same exact debug build. What is more surprising, the app launched from spring board starts normally. I would be grateful even for hints how to tackle this situation.

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention that this behaviour is 100% reproducible on iOS 9.3 and 9.3.1. I have encoutered it on iPhone 4S and 6S Plus.

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce it with the "Devices" log window open, and look for something in the device log when it crashes (running in normal mode, not debug)?

Comment: I've done it with development build: deployed via Xcode, stopped debug and started app from spring board. It didn't crash. The crash only occurs when Xcode is fully disconnected.

Comment: @Ramon: I meant, yes, the devices view with logs was open.

Comment: If your analysis is true then this is an iOS bug and should be reported to Apple.

Comment: Have you added NSLog-s to your AppDelegate to see what is called (if anything)? Is Crashlytics initialized? (Add some before-after nslog)